# Add lines to toc title

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to modify the look of my toc. In the end it should look like this:
[image]
I managed to insert the "Page" but i have no idea how to add the lines.

Here is a small working example which shows my current version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{section1}
\subsection{subsection1}
\subsection{subsection2}
\subsection{subsection3}
\section{section2}
\section{section3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What should happen on multi-line entries?

Comment: Thanks :-)
There shouldn´t be any. The names of the sections are short and the tocdepth will stay at 1.
The red lines around "page" are more important than the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion with package `tocbasic` (can not be used together with `tocloft`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand*\tocrule[2][-1.5\dp\strutbox]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\color{#2}\rule[#1]{\textwidth}{.4pt}}%
}
\newcommand*\pagenumberwithtocrule[2]{#2\tocrule{#1}}
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  ~\hfill
  \textbf{Page}%
  \tocrule{red}%
  \tocrule[\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+2\dp\strutbox]{red}%
  \par
}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  pagenumberformat=\pagenumberwithtocrule{orange}
]{tocline}{section}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{section1}
\subsection{subsection1}
\subsection{subsection2}
\subsection{subsection3}
\section{section2}
\section{section3}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just re-define the macro that renders the toc entry. The original definition is in article.cls, i just added one line (see inline comment).

Edit: Added red lines around "Page":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%% Need color package for red lines:
\usepackage{color}
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \leavevmode
  \raise\baselineskip\hbox{\rlap{\color{red}\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}}%
  ~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par
  \rlap{\color{red}\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \rlap{\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}%           <--- This line renders the rule
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{section1}
\subsection{subsection1}
\subsection{subsection2}
\subsection{subsection3}
\section{section2}
\section{section3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing, but it didn't work. I was missing the `\rlap`. Why do you need this here?

Comment: Works really well, Thanks!
 Could you do the same for the 2 red lines around "page"?

Comment: @nox `\rlap{x}` creates a right-expanding box around `x` that takes no horizontal space ("right-wise overlap").

Comment: @FlorianWaas I edited the example accordingly.

Comment: @Lupino I'm aware of that, but why is it needed here and fails to compile otherwise?